# Powershell - search for old files and email alert

Tags: powershell

Having some trouble with a powershell script which Im completely new too

What Im trying to do is basically monitor a specific folder for XML files only. If the files are older than say a 30mins then to email myself to alert me there is a problem

This is what I have so far:

```
$Path = "‪D:\Temp"
$SMTPServer = "10.1.1.12"
$From = "Email  <email@aol.com>"
$To = "emailme@whatever.com"
$Subject = "Alert: Potential issue with service"
 
 
$SMTPMessage = @{
To = $To
From = $From
Subject = "$Subject"
Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}

$File = Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter ".XML" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get- 
Date).AddMinutes(-30)}
If ($File)
{   $SMTPBody = "Batches older than 30 minutes located in D:\Temp while service is actively running. 
Service may require a restart."
$File | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n" }
Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
```

It doesnt work at all at the moment its failing at the first stage in trying to find the path

Any help would be great
Thanks

Comment: What does `Get-ChildItem -path $path` and `Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter ".XML"` return?

Comment: `-Filter` parameter expects a wildcard pattern, which should be `"*.xml"`.

Comment: It should be just at @zett42 mentioned^

Comment: Thanks for taking the time all - will add that wildcard ......Get-ChildItem -path $path comes up with a list of folders and Get-ChildItem -path $path -Filter ".XML" finds nothing unless I specify the folder to look in

Comment: Also add switch `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to ensure you will only receive FileInfo objects, not directories too.

Comment: Do you want to include subdirectories? Add `-Recurse`